# "Object does not support this property or method" in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have looked through a lot of the other questions for this issue and I have not been able to find anything that helps my specific issue. I've tried a lot of the suggestions with no help...

Here is what I am working with that is showing up with the error (and of course, only in IE, it works fine in Chrome and FF):

```
var Lights = {};
var light_data = {
    id: "",
    location: "",
    week: [],
    stats: [],
    run: function(){
        run_statistics();
    }
}

Lights.APIEvents = Object.create(light_data); //complains about this line
```

I want to create a light_data object for the properties of Lights... but it doesn't work and complains that the object doesn't support it.. any ideas?

Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: Where is the error/code?

Comment: I think you forgot to post your code.

Comment: It posted without letting me even finish typing my question...  fixing!

Comment: What version of IE are you using?  Pretty sure `Object.create` only works in IE 9+.

Comment: @Rocket spot on -> http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/

Comment: That seems to be the issue, I have < IE8... what is a good substitute that won't mess with the other browsers? I'm not super familiar with this stuff just yet, still learning!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use this before you call `Object.create`

```
if (typeof Object.create !== 'function') {
    Object.create = function (o) {
        function F() {}
        F.prototype = o;
        return new F();
    };
}
```

So `Object.create` will work in `IE` too.

Comment: Of course now that it's working there, I'm finding more issues... but those I should be able to fix. Goody :P

Comment: I have a version of IE11 where objects have a finished amount of properties and none can be added after...  Very strange.